# how to properly plot a bar using float numbers using matplotlib?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I've got 2 float number in a list named students, one is 1000000 and 1050000, but the plot shows the incorrect numbers.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig= plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
langs=['ripley', 'paris']
students = [ripley_product_price1, paris_product_price1]
ax.bar(langs,students)
plt.show()
```

[image: this is what I get:]

Comment: You can use `ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain')`.

Answer (score 1):

Your plot is correct. The values of tick labels need to be multiplied by the number in the red box (1E6).

[image]